# How to get the value of a dynamic many2many field in create() function

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I want to get the value from of a dynamically populated many2many field in create() function, but i  get this outcome [[6, False, [98]]], 98 is actually the expected outcome though
this is my code below

```
class CustomTransRequest(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.trans.request'
    _description = 'Transfer Request'

    branch_from_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string="From", required=True)
    branch_to_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string="To", required=True)
    line_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch.line', string="Products", required=True)
    product_id = fields.Many2many('custom.product', required=False, )
    qty = fields.Integer(string="Qty", required=True)

    @api.onchange('line_id')
    def onchange_line(self):
        if self.line_id:
            for rec in self:
                selected_products = rec.env['custom.branch.line'].search(
                    [('id', '=', rec.line_id.id)]).mapped('product_id')
                self.product_id = [(6, 0, selected_products.ids)]

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        print("Create Function ")
        print("SELECT id FROM custom_branch_line WHERE (branch_id = %s) AND (product_id = %s)" % (
            vals.get('branch_to_id'), vals['product_id']))
        result = super(CustomTransRequest, self).create(vals)
        return result
```

Comment: Have you tried to just use a related field for `product_id`. And have in mind the odoo naming guideline: the field should be named `product_ids` because there could be more than one `custom.product`. That's why the guidelines recommend to use `_id` for `Many2one` and `_ids` for `Many2many` and `One2many`fields.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but what do you mean by related field? can you elaborate please?

Comment: You can read about [related fields here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#reference-fields-related). Maybe that would be an easier solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how Odoo Handles X2many fields, by convention they are called command (or list of command) most of the time in the create method, the command that will be passed for your m2m fields will be:

```
 # only one command 6 which tell Odoo replace all record with the selected ids
 [(6, 0, [list_of_selected_record_ids)]
```

So in order to retrieve them just do: `vals['product_id'][0][2]`

No I don't know if you are just trying to show select query or you want to use, if you are just printing it:

```
  # replace vals['product_id'] with 
  '({})'.format(','.join(vals['product_id'][0][2]))
```

If you will execute it, use query params:

```
self.cr.execute("SELECT id FROM custom_branch_line WHERE (branch_id = %s) AND (product_id = %s)", (vals['branch_to_id'], vals['product_id'][0][2]))
```

for more information about X2many command check this:

[One2many and Many2many use a special "commands"](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#openerp-models-relationals-format)

**Note**: I assumed that this field will not be empty if not you need to check if the fields are not empty first.